# What is a "point-in-select" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was given this query to update a report, and it was taking a long time to run on my computer.

```
select  
c.category_type, t.categoryid, t.date, t.clicks  
from transactions t
join category c
    on c.category_id = t.categoryid
```

I asked the DBA if there were any issues with the query, and the DBA optimized the query in this manner:

```
select  
    (select category_type 
    from category c where c.category_id = t.categoryid) category_type, 
    categoryid,
    date, clicks
from transactions t
```

He described the first subquery as a "point-in-select". I have never heard of this before. Can someone explain this concept?

Comment: And did the second query have better performance?  I'm thinking they should be pretty similar.  Also, I've never heard of "point-in-select", and Google doesn't turn up anything either.

Comment: Any chance you provide `EXPLAIN` for both? The second query looks worse actually.

Comment: It's a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery). Note that his phrase doesn't appear in that wiki link, and I've never heard of it either. I'm surprised that this gives you significantly better performance on a modern version of an RDBMS.

Comment: I've never seen a subquery outperform a join.  Unless you have a very unusual case, subqueries should be avoided when a join is possible.

Comment: It would be simpler to ask the dba for explanation, rather than try to guess his intentions.

Answer (score 2):

I want to note that the two queries are not the same, unless the following is true:

- `transactions.categoryid` is always present in `category`.
- `category` has no duplicate values of `category_id`.

In practice, these would be true (in most databases).  The first query should be using a `left join` version for closer equivalence:

```
select c.category_type, t.categoryid, t.date, t.clicks  
from transactions t left join
     category c
     on c.category_id = t.categoryid;
```

Still not exactly the same, but more similar.

Finally, both versions should make use of an index on `category(category_id)`, and I would expect the performance to be very similar in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your DBA's query is not the same, as others noted, and afaik nonstandard SQL.  Yours is much preferable just for its simplicity alone.

It's usually not advantageous to re-write queries for performance.  It can help sometimes, but the DBMS is supposed to execute logically equivalent queries equivalently.  Failure to do so is a flaw in the query planner.

Performance issues are often a function of physical design.  In your case, I would look for indexes on the `category` and `transactions` tables that contain `categoryid` as first column.  If neither exist, your join is *O(mn)* because the `category` table must be scanned for each transaction row.

Not being a MySQL user, I can only advise you to get query planner output and look for indexing opportunities.